# enkive mail archive search functionality

Tags: centos, email, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, archive

I have set up enkive mail archive as shown in the [installation guide](http://wiki.enkive.org/index.php/Installation_Instructions), with [exchange setup](http://wiki.enkive.org/index.php/EnkiveWithExchange). Few problems that I have are:

- Archiving same email twice
- searching for recipient or sender does not complete, displays as running
- searching for content returns zero results

duplicate emails content:

Duplicated email

```
3ee31e463f3ddc21876d50b7287c5c98ee9752e3
5f3bd7a0adfa66e8bc61774dd51e7b02c8ec1a47

Return-Path: <>
Received: from win2008r2-exch.vp.local (win2008r2-exch.uk.spectrumasa.com [172.16.0.42])
    by titan.enkive.vp.local (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0BDB03AAD
    for <enkive@enkive.vp.local>; Tue, 21 Aug 2012 09:49:09 +0100 (BST)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_97b5d98d-95da-4847-9ea9-2a4498e6a305_"
Subject: enkive
To: vpadmin <vpadmin@vp.local>
From: Administrator <Administrator@vp.local>
Sender: <MicrosoftExchange329e71ec88ae4615bbc36ab6ce41109e@vp.local>
Message-ID: <a410cb46-b060-4d03-b98f-c1ef10345c96@journal.report.generator>
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 08:48:50 +0000
X-MS-Journal-Report:
Keywords:
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_97b5d98d-95da-4847-9ea9-2a4498e6a305_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Sender: Administrator@vp.local
Subject: enkive
Message-Id: <086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288@win2008r2-exch.vp.local>
To: vpadmin@vp.local

--_97b5d98d-95da-4847-9ea9-2a4498e6a305_
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Received: from WIN2008R2-EXCH.vp.local ([fe80::9988:2e26:44e4:885c]) by
 win2008r2-exch.vp.local ([fe80::9988:2e26:44e4:885c%10]) with mapi id
 14.02.0247.003; Tue, 21 Aug 2012 09:48:50 +0100
From: Administrator <Administrator@vp.local>
To: vpadmin <vpadmin@vp.local>
Subject: enkive
Thread-Topic: enkive
Thread-Index: Ac1/echHSNdIzzmARvaKZSjqJ014gw==
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 08:48:49 +0000
Message-ID: <086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288@win2008r2-exch.vp.local>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-GB
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: win2008r2-exch.vp.local
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalsize: 3334
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalarrivaltime: 21 Aug 2012 08:48:49.1648
 (UTC)
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagesource: StoreDriver
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagedirectionality: Originating
x-ms-exchange-forest-messagescope: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagescope: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BCC:
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalclientipaddress: 172.16.0.85
x-originating-ip: [172.16.0.85]
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalserveripaddress: 172.16.0.42
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagelatency: SRV=WIN2008R2-EXCH.vp.local:TOTAL=0
x-ms-exchange-organization-hygienepolicy: Standard
x-ms-exchange-organization-recipient-limit-verified: True
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

help

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html dir=3D"ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style id=3D"owaParaStyle" type=3D"text/css">P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:=
0;}</style>
</head>
<body ocsi=3D"0" fpstyle=3D"1">
<div style=3D"direction: ltr;font-family: Tahoma;color: #000000;font-size: =
10pt;">help<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_--

--_97b5d98d-95da-4847-9ea9-2a4498e6a305_--
```

Original email

```
48c17d2348c8040cc538e6043b74120213bd95a0
be4e599107da6738f5973a0a0112d8bfacb36130

Received: from WIN2008R2-EXCH.vp.local ([fe80::9988:2e26:44e4:885c]) by
 win2008r2-exch.vp.local ([fe80::9988:2e26:44e4:885c%10]) with mapi id
 14.02.0247.003; Tue, 21 Aug 2012 09:48:50 +0100
From: Administrator <Administrator@vp.local>
To: vpadmin <vpadmin@vp.local>
Subject: enkive
Thread-Topic: enkive
Thread-Index: Ac1/echHSNdIzzmARvaKZSjqJ014gw==
Date: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 08:48:49 +0000
Message-ID: <086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288@win2008r2-exch.vp.local>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-GB
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: win2008r2-exch.vp.local
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalsize: 3334
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalarrivaltime: 21 Aug 2012 08:48:49.1648
 (UTC)
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagesource: StoreDriver
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagedirectionality: Originating
x-ms-exchange-forest-messagescope: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagescope: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-BCC:
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalclientipaddress: 172.16.0.85
x-originating-ip: [172.16.0.85]
x-ms-exchange-organization-originalserveripaddress: 172.16.0.42
x-ms-exchange-organization-messagelatency: SRV=WIN2008R2-EXCH.vp.local:TOTAL=0
x-ms-exchange-organization-hygienepolicy: Standard
x-ms-exchange-organization-recipient-limit-verified: True
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

help

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html dir=3D"ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style id=3D"owaParaStyle" type=3D"text/css">P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:=
0;}</style>
</head>
<body ocsi=3D"0" fpstyle=3D"1">
<div style=3D"direction: ltr;font-family: Tahoma;color: #000000;font-size: =
10pt;">help<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_086C057A1EEEFA489DC7B5475CA7424B6D736288win2008r2exchvp_--
```